# How to import JQuery UI to angular 8 Project

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, jquery-ui, angular-cli

I'm working on angular app in which i want to implement draggable. There were questions about that in the past but nothing works for me. What I tried:

```
npm install jquery jquery-ui
```

and then adding following lines to angular.json

```
"scripts": [
  "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
  "../node_modules/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.js"
]
```

and then importing it to my component like

```
declare let $: any;
```

or

```
import $ from 'jquery';
```

or

```
import $ from 'jquery';
import 'jqueryui';
```

but I'm still getting error:

> TSLint: unused expression, expected an assignment or function call(no-unused-expression)

when placing this line in ngOnInit:

`$('#draggable' as any).draggable;`

Comment: As Artyom Krasnyuk said, jQuery isn't a great choice here. You have [other options](https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/overview) that are better suited to an Angular application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use it like (call a function):

```
$( "#draggable" ).draggable();
```

P.S: Don't use jQuery with Angular :)
Consider using drag-and-drop from Angular CDK (developed by Angular team):
https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/overview

Comment: Yes, I didn't know about Angualr material drag and drop. Works perfectly for me :). Thanks yall

Comment: doesn't work for me, the cdk is laking the functionalities I need, for exemple select multiple list items with mouse https://jqueryui.com/selectable/